# How do I create a method on a sequelize object that checks if there is an another object created that is associated with it?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Sorry, my title is probably confusing.

So I have three objects I created with sequelize in javascript.  User, Post, and Vote that are all associated with one another. I want to create a method on the Post model to check if the current signed in User has voted on this particular post.  I am using the Passport module for user sign in/sign out.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Votes = db.sequelize.define('votes',{
    post_id:{
        type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        unique:"voted_user"
    },
    user_id:{
        type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        unique:"voted_user"
    }
},{
    underscored: true
});
```

For that you can use the concept of the `composite key` , by defining the `unique:"voted_user"` , 
This will throw error when we try to enter same combination ,

```
model.Votes.create({ post_id : 1 , user_id : 2 }).then(data => {
    // Success
}).catch(err => {
    // Error
})
```